# cannot convert from 'const jchar *' to 'const wchar_t *'

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, java-native-interface

This is an error getting thrown from .cpp file.I am using visual studio 10 and windows7 32 bit and am compiling from eclipse indigo

```
AUWideString(JNIEnv* jni, jstring jstr)
    : mJni(jni),
      mJString(jstr),
      mString(0)
    {
        if (jstr != 0) {
            mString = jni->GetStringChars(jstr, 0);
        }
    }

    ~AUWideString()
    {
        mJni->ReleaseStringChars(mJString, mString);
    }

    operator const wchar_t*() const
    {
        return mString;
    }
    **error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'const jchar *' to 'const wchar_t *'
            Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
    error C2664: 'JNIEnv_::ReleaseStringChars' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'const wchar_t *' to 'const jchar *'****
```

how should this be resolved?

Comment: from my knowledge a wchar_t is a char exactly 4(maybe 8) bits in length, so your mString is to large in memory and needs to be reduced.

Comment: `wchar_t` is 16-bit on Windows. It is used in strings for holding UTF-16 encoded codeunits.

Answer (score 2):

`jchar` is defined as `unsigned short`, not `wchar_t`.  However, on Windows, both are 16-bit in size, so you can use a type-cast when needed, as the first compiler error says.  You should also be defining `mString` as a `jchar*` instead of a `wchar_t*` since that is what JNI actually works with.  That would eliminate the second error message.

Try this:

```
class AUWideString
{
private:
    JNIEnv* mJni;
    jstring mJString;
    jchar* mString;
    ...

public:
    AUWideString(JNIEnv* jni, jstring jstr)
        : mJni(jni),
          mJString(jstr),
          mString(0)
    {
        if (mJString != 0)
            mString = mJni->GetStringChars(mJString, 0);
    }

    ~AUWideString()
    {
        if ((mJString != 0) && (mString != 0))
            mJni->ReleaseStringChars(mJString, mString);
    }

    operator const wchar_t*() const
    {
        return reinterpret_cast<const wchar_t*>(mString);
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply,yesterday I figured I had messed up my settings with VS 10 and windows7, i reinstalled the whole setup in windows xp 32 bit with visual studio .net 2003 and got it working.